# Baidu javascript errors

Tags: javascript

I recently added a custom window.onerror function to my site to send me any client facing javascript issues that I wouldn't encounter through local 
testing.

Weirdly, as soon as this was enabled I started getting messages from the user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)".

Here's some sample data that got given to the onerror function by the Baidu bot.

```
eventPhase: 3
currentTarget: [object DOMWindow]
cancelable: false
target: [object HTMLScriptElement]
bubbles: true
type: error
cancelBubble: false
clipboardData: undefined
srcElement: [object HTMLScriptElement]
defaultPrevented: false
timeStamp: 1441375534468
returnValue: true
stopPropagation: function stopPropagation() { [native code] }
preventDefault: function preventDefault() { [native code] }
initEvent: function initEvent() { [native code] }
stopImmediatePropagation: function stopImmediatePropagation() { [native code] }
CAPTURING_PHASE: 1
AT_TARGET: 2
BUBBLING_PHASE: 3
MOUSEDOWN: 1
MOUSEUP: 2
MOUSEOVER: 4
MOUSEOUT: 8
MOUSEMOVE: 16
MOUSEDRAG: 32
CLICK: 64
DBLCLICK: 128
KEYDOWN: 256
KEYUP: 512
KEYPRESS: 1024
DRAGDROP: 2048
FOCUS: 4096
BLUR: 8192
SELECT: 16384
CHANGE: 32768
```

This is unlike any other error call the site has gotten. Normally I get an actual error message, but with the Baidu bot it's just a blob of data.

I'm curious does anyone know more about this?
I can only assume there's no problem with the actual javascript on the site, since the bot is the only client sending errors like this. Is it possible that the bot is just injecting its own javascript into the site's source and that contains some error, or maybe the bot is purposely calling the window.onerror to see how websites react to it or something like that?

Comment: I can't find anything that is about Baidu spider causing problems in JavaScript. The [only thing](https://www.v2ex.com/t/203602) that comes up a lot is that it sends a lot of request from tons of different ip at the same time.